# ionic collection-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When I refer the item individualy on angularJS it works fine, but in collection not work.

This colletcion not working in my ionic project, anyone knows what is wrong ?? thanks !

//JavaScript part

//HTML part

```
MapApp.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.itens = [
        {titulo: 'Mapa'},
        {titulo: 'Login'},
        {titulo: 'Sobre'}
    ];



    $scope.TituloMenu = 'Menu';
    //$scope.currItens = $scope.itens;
});





<!-- NOT WORK -->
   <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/map/login" 
    collection-item-height="52" collection-repeat"item in itens" class="item item-icon-left" 
     item-height="250" item-width="100%">
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>{{item.titulo}}
   </ion-item>

<!-- IT WORK -->
   <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/map/login"  class="item item-icon-left" >
        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>{{itens[0].titulo}}
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/map/login"  class="item item-icon-left" >
        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>{{itens[1].titulo}}
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/map/login"  class="item item-icon-left" >
        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>{{itens[2].titulo}}
   </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an equals sign in the html.

```
collection-repeat"item in itens" 

collection-repeat="item in itens"
```